# Sitecore - Could Not Find File 'C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Temp\yyyyyy.dll

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

When users in the CMS try to add an external link, they are presented with a page and an error of:

Could Not Find File `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Temp\yyyyyy.dll`

Where User Name is the AD Account name tied to the Databases. I looked in the directory and no such dll exists, which tells me it is not writing to the temp directory as Sitecore has some sort of permissions issue. Have others seen this, and if so, how did you resolve it?

Comment: Is it `yyyyy.dll` or you just hid the name of dll? When does it happen exactly? Is it when the selector is initiated, when user selects link, when user saves the item?

Comment: It is not the name of the dll, and occurs when a user tries to edit an item. I just found that the Master DB lost its Execute permission during a DB Restore, so I suspect that may be the case. About to test post an IIS Reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user account did not have execute permissions to the Master and Core Databases. Once these were applied, along with an IIS reset, the issue was resolved.